# Anyone has idea on how to approach a 3 level listview?

Tags: listview

need some help on how to approach the following scenario:

if I select Products it expands to Product Details, and once clicked
it expands to product SKU (not part of the details), so altogether this 
is 3 levels. if anyone has experience I'd appreciate it very much if you could
share it.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) has a TreeListView flavour, which could very easily be configured to behave in this way.

A TreeListView is basically a combination of a tree structure with columns like a ListView:[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/treelistview.png))</sub>

Here the three levels are Artist/Album/Song, but it could easily be your product/details/SKU.